# Using lodash debounce in Angular2 & Typescript scroll not working

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have the following code which calls a lodash debounce function:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
    if (myBoolean) 
       _.debounce(this.onScrollDown(), 1500, false);

    }
}

private onScrollDown() {
    console.log("onScrollDown")
}
```

But I'm getting this error in my console:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'.
```

And the following on browser:

```
TypeError: Expected a function
    at Function.debounce
```

I'm using typescript by the way

Comment: You're not passing a function into .debounce? You're passing a called function which returns undefined

Comment: I'm using it now like this and still not works: `_.debounce( ()=> {
                    console.log("onScrollDown")
                }, 1500, {});`

Comment: Define "not works".

Comment: @JBNizet does not print the console.log in 1st paramete

Comment: Every time there is a scroll, you're creating a debounced function, but you don't do anything with this created function. It's not stored anywhere, and never called. What you probably want to do is creating a debounced function, once and for all, and calling that debounced function every time there is a scroll.

Comment: @JBNizet can you plese post an example of how to store it and call it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not familiar with lodash, but I think what you want is:

```
private debouncedOnScroll = _.debounce(() => this.onScrollDown(), 1500, {});

@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
    this.debouncedOnScroll();
}

private onScrollDown() {
    console.log("onScrollDown")
}
```

Comment: how to pass parameters inside the debounce?

Comment: You need to be clearer than that. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: if I wanted to use some parameters inside onScrollDown how to achieve that? let says I want to print private onScrollDown() {
    console.log(myString)
}

Comment: Where does myString come from? As it is in your example, it would be a global variable. Also, have you read the documentation? https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

Comment: onWindowScroll() { let myString = "fizz";
    this.debouncedOnScroll();
}

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. to me. Edit your question, post valid code, and explain what you expect it to do. The browser won't pass any argument other than the scoll event to onWindowScroll(), so I really don't see what you would want to pass as argument except this event.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to JB Nizet I could solve my need this is my approach:

### 1) Create function you want to debounce:

```
private projectsLoad(myParameter): void {
   // function code here...
};
```

### 2) Assign it to a field/member of the class:

```
private debounceProjectsLoad = _.debounce(
    (myParameter) => this.projectsLoad(myParameter),
    1500,
    true
);
```

### 3) Call the debounced field/meber when neeeded:

```
public loadProjectsGroup(myParameter: string): void {
    this.debounceProjectsLoad(myParameter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation.
Note: In Step 2., you can leave the third param empty or if you want to fill it up, should be an object